# Using CameraCaptureUI in Windows 10 fullscreen

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime

Is their a way to tell the [CameraCaptureUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui), that it should start in fullscreen mode, instead of a small window?

my current code from the linked webside:

```
CameraCaptureUI cameraUI = new CameraCaptureUI();

Windows.Storage.StorageFile capturedMedia =
    await cameraUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);
```

My Application is based on WinRT for Windows 8.1.

On a Win 8 Client the Camera App just start in fullscreen, but with a Win 10 Client it open the Camera App in a small window

Comment: hi , have u fixed this issue am also facing same issue ?

Comment: @arjun-t-raj yes just watch the comments on the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no current way to control the size of the CameraCaptureUI window from a UWP app.

The dev team is aware that people are concerned about this and is watching the UserVoice request at [How can we improve the Windows dev platform?](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/10440042-improve-cameracaptureui-on-windows-10-desktop) You can vote and comment there to help the team understand the need and prioritize appropriately.

Comment: so i have to implement the camera function into my app to use it in fullscreen?

Comment: Yes. If you want to customize the camera experience you can implement it yourself with MediaCapture

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to use the CameraCaptureUI class to take a picture. The code is from file CapturePhoto.xaml.cs of the [Camera capture UI sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=249441). The dialog with the user occurs when you call the asynchronous method [CaptureFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.capturefileasync).

```
// Using Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI API to capture a photo

 CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
 Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
 dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;

 StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```